# Binomial coefficients bounded by entropy exponential

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, information-theory

So I'm trying to prove that for $\frac{1}{2}< x \leq 1$ we have

$$\sum_{\lceil nx \rceil}^{n}{n \choose k} \leq 2^{nh(x)}$$

I've managed to prove that $$\sum_{0}^{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{ n\choose k}\leq2^{nH(1-x,x)}$$

But when I try to progress from the fact that $\sum_{0}^{n}{n \choose k}=2^{n}$ I seem to be getting the inequality sign the wrong way round. Can anyone help?

Comment: By $H(1−x,x)$ you mean $h(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=\lceil n x \rceil}^{n}{n \choose k} =  \sum_{k=\lceil nx \rceil}^{n}{n \choose n-k}  = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n \lambda \rfloor}{n \choose j}  $$

where in the later $ n - \lceil n x \rceil=\lfloor n(1-x)\rfloor = \lfloor n \lambda\rfloor $, with $\lambda = 1-x$, $0\le \lambda < 1/2$

Then see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820230/prove-that-bitstrings-with-1-0-ratio-different-from-50-50-are-compressable/822061).