# a problem involving binary entropy function

Tags: calculus, probability, information-theory, entropy

let $\alpha<1/2$ such that $2^{H(\alpha)}\le 2^{1-\epsilon}$,when $H$ is binary entropy function.

how can i prove that then we have:

$2^{n(1-\epsilon)}\ge \sum\limits_{i\le \alpha n } {n \choose i}$?

thank u

Comment: see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820230/prove-that-bitstrings-with-1-0-ratio-different-from-50-50-are-compressable/822061